# Linear combination of coordinates of random unit vector

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, probability-distributions

Let $v\in \mathbb{R}^n$ be uniformly distributed on the unit sphere. Let $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n$ be given real numbers. What is the distribution of
$$X=\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_iv_i^2\;?$$
Does it happen to belong to any known family of distributions? I think this is a very flexible way to model the distribution with compact support. When $n=2$, $X$ is just the celebrated arcsine distribution supported on $(\lambda_{\min},\lambda_{\max})$. What about for general $n$? I also think $X$ can capture the ''spreadness'' of the sequence $\lambda_1,..,\lambda_n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The distribution of $X$ is the distribution of the ratio 
$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_iZ_i^2}{\sum_{i=1}^nZ_i^2}
$$
of two quadratic forms in iid standard normal random variables $Z_1,\dots,Z_n$ (because the distribution of $(v_1,\dots,v_n)$ is the same as that of $(Z_1,\dots,Z_n)\big/\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^nZ_i^2}$). The distribution of such ratios was studied by [Gurland](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=2ahUKEwiDoeDbrP3hAhUOEawKHTKNBtsQFjACegQIAxAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcowles.yale.edu%2Fsites%2Fdefault%2Ffiles%2Ffiles%2Fpub%2Fcdp%2Fs-0354.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1xMd5R-PTGs0rvjHtme9W8); also see e.g. [Watson](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1955AuJPh...8..402W).

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: I am glad this was of help.